# Maps can't display in one of my panel variants?

Tags: views, panels, location, google-maps

I have a strange and frustrating issue since hours, I can't find any solution:

I got a node template in panel with severals panels where I use gmap views to show addresses used by node, with nid argument node ref and so on. This work fine.

I cloned this working setup to another variant (another content type, other gmap views) and this absolutely refuses to show the map.

. Arguments are OK: I can retrieve the right address as unformatted (its a node reference) from another display of the view

. If I configure my gmap view to display unformatted, this shows up.

. Just in case I setupped the content type to have a location field but I don't see the point it's just a desperate act.

. I disabled other contents in the variant: does not show up

. I reused th same gmap working view in the variant: does not show up

. I made some coffee and turns three times around my desk: does not show up

What is the huge thing I am missing?

Here is a panel export of the faulty variant there's only the gmap content within it:

```
$handler = new stdClass;
$handler->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default handler disabled initially */
$handler->api_version = 1;
$handler->name = 'node_view_panel_context_5';
$handler->task = 'node_view';
$handler->subtask = '';
$handler->handler = 'panel_context';
$handler->weight = 5;
$handler->conf = array(
  'title' => 'test',
  'no_blocks' => 0,
  'pipeline' => 'standard',
  'css_id' => 'adresses-formations',
  'css' => '',
  'contexts' => array(),
  'relationships' => array(),
  'access' => array(
    'logic' => 'and',
    'plugins' => array(
      0 => array(
        'name' => 'role',
        'settings' => array(
          'rids' => array(
            0 => 8,
            1 => 5,
            2 => 7,
            3 => 10,
            4 => 3,
          ),
        ),
        'context' => 'logged-in-user',
        'not' => FALSE,
      ),
      1 => array(
        'name' => 'node_type',
        'settings' => array(
          'type' => array(
            'alphabetisation_formations' => 'alphabetisation_formations',
          ),
        ),
        'context' => 'argument_nid_1',
        'not' => FALSE,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
$display = new panels_display;
$display->layout = 'onecol';
$display->layout_settings = array(
  'items' => array(
    'canvas' => array(
      'type' => 'row',
      'contains' => 'column',
      'children' => array(
        0 => 'main',
      ),
      'parent' => NULL,
    ),
    'main' => array(
      'type' => 'column',
      'width' => 100,
      'width_type' => '%',
      'children' => array(
        0 => 1,
        1 => 'main-row',
        2 => 2,
      ),
      'parent' => 'canvas',
    ),
    'main-row' => array(
      'type' => 'row',
      'contains' => 'region',
      'children' => array(
        0 => 'center',
        1 => 'right',
      ),
      'parent' => 'main',
    ),
    'center' => array(
      'type' => 'region',
      'title' => 'Center',
      'width' => 50,
      'width_type' => '%',
      'parent' => 'main-row',
    ),
    1 => array(
      'type' => 'row',
      'contains' => 'region',
      'children' => array(
        0 => 'presentation',
      ),
      'parent' => 'main',
      'class' => '',
    ),
    'presentation' => array(
      'type' => 'region',
      'title' => 'presentation',
      'width' => 100,
      'width_type' => '%',
      'parent' => '1',
      'class' => '',
    ),
    2 => array(
      'type' => 'row',
      'contains' => 'region',
      'children' => array(
        0 => 'node_complet',
      ),
      'parent' => 'main',
      'class' => '',
    ),
    'node_complet' => array(
      'type' => 'region',
      'title' => 'node complet',
      'width' => 100,
      'width_type' => '%',
      'parent' => '2',
      'class' => '',
    ),
    'right' => array(
      'type' => 'region',
      'title' => 'right',
      'width' => 50,
      'width_type' => '%',
      'parent' => 'main-row',
      'class' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
$display->panel_settings = array(
  'style_settings' => array(
    'default' => NULL,
    'middle' => NULL,
    'center' => NULL,
    'presentation' => NULL,
    'node_complet' => NULL,
    'right' => NULL,
    'top' => NULL,
    'contact_' => NULL,
    'old' => NULL,
    'old_' => NULL,
    'old__' => NULL,
    'type_cours' => NULL,
    'old___' => NULL,
  ),
);
$display->cache = array();
$display->title = '%node:title</BR>%node:field_organisme-link';
$display->content = array();
$display->panels = array();
  $pane = new stdClass;
  $pane->pid = 'new-1';
  $pane->panel = 'middle';
  $pane->type = 'views';
  $pane->subtype = 'adresses_principale_formation';
  $pane->shown = TRUE;
  $pane->access = array();
  $pane->configuration = array(
    'override_pager_settings' => 0,
    'use_pager' => 0,
    'nodes_per_page' => '10',
    'pager_id' => '',
    'offset' => '0',
    'more_link' => 0,
    'feed_icons' => 0,
    'panel_args' => 1,
    'link_to_view' => 0,
    'args' => '%node:nid',
    'url' => '',
    'display' => 'default',
    'context' => array(
      0 => '',
    ),
    'override_title' => 1,
    'override_title_text' => '',
  );
  $pane->cache = array();
  $pane->style = array(
    'settings' => array(),
    'style' => 'stylizer',
  );
  $pane->css = array(
    'css_id' => '',
    'css_class' => '',
  );
  $pane->extras = array();
  $pane->position = 0;
  $display->content['new-1'] = $pane;
  $display->panels['middle'][0] = 'new-1';
$display->hide_title = PANELS_TITLE_FIXED;
$display->title_pane = '0';
$handler->conf['display'] = $display;
```

Comment: could paste the relevant panel setup screenshots. the one which works and the one which doesn't

Comment: done. if I change the view used here to display unformatted, this works.. could be my content type ?

Comment: Instead of using "clone variant," try deleting the cloned variant and re-creating it manually.

Comment: sorry actually by 'cloned' I meant recreated 'by hand'. I just reused a custom layout.

Comment: this is not an answer, but I couldn't post any comment so... bear with me.
I'd like to know if you manage to solve the issue, since I'm having similar issue with yours and have been struggling for hours now. In my case, though, it was fine yesterday when I last saved my work, now not even a preview anywhere show up.